# Android. Downloaded .docx files converting to .bin files

Tags: android, parsing, android-intent, uri, bin

I am trying to download .docx file. Using intent to send link to browser to make it handle URL. File is downloading. But file is in .bin sometimes without extention. My code looks like this:

```
        String url = documentList.get(position).getManMadeLink();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
```

How to solve this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: if it's just a normal URL you can just download it yourself using a HTTP connection.

Comment: what if url is not direct. i mean http://dev.businessinfo.uz/document/template/download/link/528b07d162135. i think link is processed in server. so i need to use browser in order to go to url -> then this url redirects to needed document. And how to be in this situation? Still I can download using HTTP?